# C: Scanning a file from stdin

Tags: c, list, stdin

I'm trying to fill 2 lists from a file using stdin,it's working for some files but not for all my files.

here my code:

```
int k;
int taille = 1;  // TAILLE  A 1  ??
int val;
char caractere;

while (scanf("%d%c", &val, &caractere) > 0 && caractere != '\n') {
    taille++;
} 

printf("taille: %d\n", taille ); //size

int liste[taille];
int permut[taille];

rewind(stdin);    

int j=0;
while (scanf("%d", &k) == 1) {
    if(j < taille){
        liste[j]=k;
    }
    else{
        permut[j-taille]=k;
     }
    j++;
 }

int c=0;

for(c;c<taille;c++){
    printf("per: %d\n", liste[c] );
}
```

for a working file (file10):

```
1 2 3 4 6 5
1 2 3 4 6 5
```

cmd:

```
./perm < test/test10.in
```

output:

```
taille: 6
per: 1
per: 2
per: 3
per: 4
per: 6
per: 5
```

and here's my probleme (file9 is exactly like file10):

```
1 2 3 4 6 5
1 2 3 4 6 5
```

cmd:

```
./perm < test/test9.in
```

output:

```
taille: 13
per: 1
per: 2
per: 3
per: 4
per: 6
per: 5
per: 1
per: 2
per: 3
per: 4
per: 6
per: 5
per: 0
```

Comment: Now is a great time to learn how to use a debugger and how to step through your code line by line while monitoring the variables and their values.

Comment: Also, compare the two files in e.g. a hex editor (or use any other comparison program) to make sure the two files really are the same, and if not why not copy the working over the non-working?

Comment: I print the character in the first while loop and i found that in the non working files there are two carriages return that are not in the working files, i tried the copy paste but not working.
I'm going to try the comparison

Comment: try `while (scanf("%d%c", &val, &caractere) > 0 && caractere != '\n' && caractere != '\r') {`

Comment: Ok hex editor confirm that, there are carriages return, but i don't why there are CR and not in my new files i did them with the same editor lol so i remove all and make them again (sorry for the english)
Thank you Joachim

Comment: yeah it's working i don't why i didn't think about that thank you Bluepixy